# Django: assigning a foreign key of class that hasn't been created yet

Tags: python, sql, django

I have the relational database and one of the relations looks like this:

```
Student < --- > Major_enrollments
```

So I need to create a column with a foreign key to the second table in both tables. How can I do so in the view of the fact, that if I define the class e.g. Student first, I will be notified with such error: "**NameError: name 'Major_enrollments' is not defined**".

This is a piece of code I wrote (models.py):

```
class Students(models.Model):

    nr_album = models.IntegerField()
    fName = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    lName = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    pesel = models.BigIntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    major_enrollments = models.ForeignKey(Major_enrollments) #<---THAT DOESN'T WORK

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.pesel)


    class Meta:
        db_table='Students'

class Major_enrollments(models.Model):
    majors = models.ForeignKey(Majors)
    students = models.ForeignKey(Students)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.id)

    class Meta:
        db_table='Major_enrollments'
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the class name (as a string) instead of class itself:

```
class Students(models.Model):

    nr_album = models.IntegerField()
    fName = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    lName = models.CharField(max_length=70)
    pesel = models.BigIntegerField()
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    major_enrollments = models.ForeignKey('Major_enrollments')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.pesel)


    class Meta:
        db_table='Students'
```

Comment: +1, also you could use `'<app_name>.Major_enrollments'` from an external module

Comment: Wow I didn't expect a response so quickly, nice :)).. It worked but I needed to ad also a 'related name' in both tables so it looks like this:

    major_enrollments = models.ForeignKey('Major_enrollments', related_name='Students_major_enrollments')

Thanks :)))!!!!

Answer (score 2):

Use a string with the name of the class as described in the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey

Comment: Instead of posting an already given answer you could edit the one by @PavelAnossov to add the documentation link